# submit button can't find save method

Tags: codeigniter-4

I have a form that use submit button. My submit button always refer to mypages.com/pages/save, but my save function can appear with mypages.com/save. are there any ways to make my submit button refer to /save not /pages/save?

I put this in my route, but not work

```
$routes->get('/save', 'pages::save');
```

[this is what happend when I try /pages/save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Zypx.png)

[and this what happen when I try /save, its error cause it suppose open when I hit submit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAA7d.png)

this is my save function

```
    public function save()
{

    $beli = $this->request->getvar('berasbeli');
    $this->zakatModel->save(
        [
            'nama' => $this->request->getVar('nama'),
            'alamat' => $this->request->getVar('alamat'),
            'telp' => $this->request->getvar('telp'),
            'jmlhjiwa' => $this->request->getVar('jmlhjiwa'),
            'berasbeli' => $this->request->getVar('berasbeli'),
            'ttlbeli' =>  (int)$beli * 38000,
            'berasbawa' => $this->request->getvar('berasbawa'),
            'ttlberas' => $this->request->getvar('berasbawa') + $this->request->getVar('berasbeli'),
            'maal' => $this->request->getVar('maal'),
            'berasinfaq' => $this->request->getVar('berasinfaq'),
            'infaq' => $this->request->getvar('infaq'),
            'fidyah' => $this->request->getVar('fidyah'),
            'penerima' => $this->request->getVar('penerima'),

        ]
    );


    session()->setFlashdata('pesan', 'Upload Berhasil');


    return redirect()->to('/');
```

This is the submit button

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

Comment: add your view to this  question - validate the input of save method like this :https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/validation.html#form-validation-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you have added *nama* **allow field** into model and 2nd check that you are receiving data into getVar you can use `return var_dump($beli);` to check which data your are recieved. Cos *nama* is compulsory field in database.

Your /save url working properly